# Where to report ? some user has not valid vot-up

Tags: discussion, moderators, user-accounts

Hello **@all** and Moderators,

I see many users get not valid votes from the right users. They used the sock puppet's accounts or missed the use of our community members' accounts. I added one user's reputation here. He/she got all votes up at the same time in a day. we did not have access Moderator tool to check users' activity and who gives votes to this user.

**So how can I report this user activity and where I can do this action?**

Please check below image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flag one of the user's posts explaining what the problem is.

Comment: This user has miss used vote-up, https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/104791/izanova

Comment: Maya be he used a sock puppet account or miss use of community members.

Comment: You can show his account history all votes up at are the same time, which is not possible at all times. May he is doing something wrong.

Comment: thanks for the info.

Comment: Hi @Marius, today I noticed that this user's reputation seems questionable. Could you take a look? https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/97591/mohammad-bharmal?tab=reputation .Thanks.

Comment: @TuVan. thanks for the heads up. the system autocorected the reputation.